# GET Request working properly on Insomnia and curl, but not on axios

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I'm having a strange issue in React + NextJS using axios. If I do a GET request using Insomnia or `curl` on the terminal the response is what I'm expecting from my local nodejs backend API. I even inserted the URL of the request on the browser and it also worked properly. But when I do the GET request on axios, the "content" field of the object received is undefined.

The object received properly on Insomnia, `curl` and browser:

```
    {
        "_id": "64933d858ffd354b57b808a7",
        "messageId": "createdd-dc9a-40ee-b376-b4fd255c9075",
        "content": "Room VISOR has been created!",
        "timestamp": "2023-06-21T18:12:21.395Z",
        "author": "mariliarf",
        "room": "VISOR",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "64933d858ffd354b57b808aa",
        "messageId": "joindf66-8b6b-4e32-9409-322a7ad9c790",
        "content": "mariliarf has joined the room",
        "timestamp": "2023-06-21T18:12:21.332Z",
        "author": "mariliarf",
        "room": "VISOR",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

The object received using axios as seen on my chrome devtools console:

```
{
  "author": "mariliarf",
  "content": undefined,
  "id": "joindf66-8b6b-4e32-9409-322a7ad9c790",
  "messageId": "joindf66-8b6b-4e32-9409-322a7ad9c790",
  "room": "VISOR",
  "timestamp": "2023-06-21T18:12:21.332Z"
},
{
  "author": "mariliarf",
  "content": undefined,
  "id": "eba12aa7-453f-4a2d-aed3-fd932303c57f",
  "messageId": "eba12aa7-453f-4a2d-aed3-fd932303c57f",
  "room": "VISOR",
  "timestamp": "2023-06-21T18:12:28.492Z"
}
```

This is the code of the request that is inside a `useEffect` hook:

```
const messagespath = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + '/messages/room/' + room
const messagesresponseGET = await axios.get(messagespath)
console.log(messagesresponseGET)
```

My lib versions from my `package.json`:

```
...
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"next": "13.4.6",
...
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```